# How to fix errors in a speedometer academic assignment?

Tags: java, overriding

I'm not great with coding but got roped into making a speedometer app using Java for my robotics class. There are many errors and I'm just not sure how to fix them.

Some of the exact problems are:

```
1:          location.setUseMericUnits(this.useMetricUnits());
            nCurrentSpeed = location.getSpeed()
```

useMetricUnits is underlined in red saying "cannot resolve method 'useMetricUnits()'

```
2:         if(this.useMetricUnits()){
    tv_speed.setText(strCurrentSpeed + " km/h");
```

It has the same issue with useMetricUnits

```
3:    private boolean useMetricUnits() {
        return Sw_metric.isChecked();
```

useMetricUnits() says `; expected and return Sw_metric.isChecked() says cannot return a value from a method with a void result type`

```
4:   @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,@NonNull String[] permissions,
        @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
```

@Override says annotations not allowed here, (int request says ; expected and @NonNull says identifier expected for both of them

```
 private void updateSpeed(CLocation location){
    float nCurrentSpeed = 0;

    if(location != null){
        location.setUseMericUnits(this.useMetricUnits());
        nCurrentSpeed = location.getSpeed();
    }

    Formatter fmt = new Formatter(new StringBuilder());
    fmt.format(Locale.US, "%5.1" , nCurrentSpeed);
    String strCurrentSpeed = fmt.toString();
    strCurrentSpeed =strCurrentSpeed.replace(" ", "0");

    if(this.useMetricUnits()){
        tv_speed.setText(strCurrentSpeed + " km/h");
    }
    else {
        tv_speed.setText(strCurrentSpeed + " mp/h");
}
private boolean useMetricUnits() {
    return Sw_metric.isChecked();
}

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,@NonNull String[] permissions,
    @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if(requestCode == 1000) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            doStuff();
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }
}
}}
```

It's supposed to be a speedometer, and I'm not sure what is wrong with the code.

Comment: setUse!!Meric!!Units in first one - typo?

Answer (score 2):

You either forgot the closing bracket for the else clause at the end of `updateSpeed`, or the closing bracket for the `updateSpeed` method.

The result is that the end of the `updateSpeed` method occurs at the second-to-last bracket in the code that you posted, and the other two methods are defined *inside* `updateSpeed`.

Adding another } before `useMetricUnits` should solve the errors you're seeing:

```
...
    else {
        tv_speed.setText(strCurrentSpeed + " mp/h");
    }
}

private boolean useMetricUnits() {
    return Sw_metric.isChecked();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if(requestCode == 1000) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            doStuff();
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked but now I am attempting to use the app on my phone and it automatically closes as it is opened. Do you have any advice, or could you help me?

Comment: As you stated it is due soon, I expect I'm too late anyway.  However, from just the code snippet you posted, I do not know why it would be closing immediately.  Perhaps finish() is being called?

Comment: I made a whole other post about it do you want the link or whatever? It's due tomorrow.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55485971/my-java-speedometer-mobile-app-will-compile-but-not-start#